# How well did the Sky Wizards Academy BD/DVD sell in Japan?

Tags: sky-wizards-academy

Can you tell me how many Sky Wizards Academy BD/DVDs were sold in Japan? I kinda liked this series and want to know if it will get a season 2.

Comment: The last volume (#6) doesn't go on sale until Feb 26, 2016, so you won't have good sales figures available until a couple weeks after that.

Comment: I've undeleted this and am leaving a comment to that effect to protect this post from the roomba. I'd post an answer to this question as-is, but it seemed a bit improprietous to mod-undelete and answer right away, so I'll let it sit a few days.

Comment: @senshin:  If you know the answer, I don't have any personal qualms with you answering it, *especially* since it was originally deleted by the roomba, **and** it can be answered in 2016 (and beyond).

Comment: If anyone knows the answer then plz answer it.

Comment: @senshin gentle poke, in case you are still considering answering this question?